# SQL Server : error on converting varchar to decimal / float

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting an error while trying to convert the `varchar` to `decimal`.

I found the place of error but unable to rectify it.

The code I use is:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.PAYMENTS.recdate, 3) AS rdate,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL, dbo.PAYMENTS.amount),
    dbo.PAYMENTS.balance
FROM 
    dbo.PAYMENTS
```

I got an error message:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

The error occurs due to a value `-5.862` which is in the `amount` column.

I try by changing the value `-5.862` to `5` then it works properly.

Anyone please help me to convert `varchar` to `decimal` with the value `-5.862`

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing numeric values in a text column?

Comment: Can you try this, and tell me what you get back: `select convert(varchar(10), -5.862)`. Also, can you try replacing the dot with a comma in the column, and see if that removes this problem? Note that you still have to specify precision when using `DECIMAL`, but let's focus on the exception first.

Comment: I got the results as -5.862

Comment: OK, then the value in that column isn't `-5.862`, but something that looks like it. Can you copy out the actual value from the column and paste it, not retype it? Note that spaces before or after the value doesn't create this problem. I'm guessing someone copied a value from Word and pasted it into your application, which stored it in the database, and now you got a hyphen, not a minus, but let's try to figure it out.

Comment: The value is  - 5.862    this is the paste value

Comment: You have a space between minus sign and numbers which messes the conversion

Comment: i think there might me some error on another value also. Is there any command to check it out in which value the error is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your help. is there any way to remove this space in sql

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any good ways to troubleshoot such an issue since presumably *you shouldn't put bad data into your table in the first place*.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's not going to help the OP as he is on 2005, but it's worth to note that SQL Server 2012 has introduced a nice `TRY_CONVERT` functions that return NULL if conversion can't be done - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb151/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is twofold:

1. You're storing numeric values as text
2. You're not validating the input to that text column

Your comment says your value is stored like this: `- 5.862`, and not like this: `-5.862`.

So here's some SQL to try out:

```
select convert(decimal, '-5.862')
select convert(decimal, '- 5.862')
```

notice that the first "works" (but lets come back to that), the second throws that exception.

The **real** answer here is to **not** store numeric values as text, but instead store them in a proper numerical data type to begin with. Barring that, *at least* validate the input, making sure you don't allow non-numeric values creeping into the database in that column, like not allowing spaces between the minus sign and the number.

**DO NOT let bad data enter your table**. You're not saving *any* work by doing that. The validation and fixups you need to perform to get your existing data to work is much better placed at the point where the data enters your table.

A "quick fix" akin to just keeping your pants warm is this:

```
select convert(decimal, replace('- 5.862', ' ', ''))
```

But this just postpones the problem until someone enters this:

```
-5,862
twenty
!27
```

ie. something else that cannot be converted either. Since you're storing them as text, you need to do all the work to fix bad values *where you use them* instead of *where they originate*.

However, there's another problem, as suggested by the others here, and that is that `DECIMAL` by default doesn't allow for any digits after the decimal point, so the one that works above produces just `-6`.

To fix *that* problem, specify the precision:

```
select convert(decimal(18, 5), '-5.862')
```

However, and I cannot say this strongly enough: **do not store numerical values as text**. It's a disaster waiting to happen (which you have already figured out).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help and suggestion. But i am working to someone database and I have not authorised to change anything on it. I can only read the data. Once Again thanks for your help.